# How do i debug Java native calls in Eclipse?

Tags: java, c, eclipse

Is there a way to debug a native call (f.e. OpenCV calls) from java in eclipse? If so, what can i do?

I know that it is possible inside a Maven-Project, but i don't want to have one.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Support_seamless_debugging_between_JDT_and_CDT)?

Comment: It may work, but i think it would be nice to have a way without touching the java code. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: It seems that the installation is not working too well.

Comment: Oh wait, you want to debug only native code (c/c++) in Eclipse?  I thought you wanted to chain the debuggers so you can move in and out of the native calls.

Comment: I want to debug native calls. That includes the calling methods in java, but if it is possible i don't want to edit the java code for this.

Comment: So you want to debug both Java and native code in Eclipse? You need 2 debuggers for this - one for each. Isn't it like chaining the debuggers as I thought in first place? I don't understand how debugging is related to editing Java code.

Comment: I cant really install your plug-in suggestion, because eclipse is telling me that either there is no plug-in or that it does not want to install the found plug-in. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: I guess not, it's pretty old and probably broke. Until someone answers, I would suggest a lot of Googeling for a solution.